# Wrapping C API taking raw pointers by C++ function that takes iterators

Tags: c++

What is the best way to wrap a C API that takes plain pointers by a funtion that takes iterators?

I am trying to wrap a legacy API that takes pointers and size to contigious memory. However in my wrapper I would like to provide an iterator based interface.

Here is an example to illustrate the problem:

```
// C-Api
bool socket_send(void* buffer, size_t size);

// C++ Wrapper
class Socket {
    template <...>
    bool send(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
         ...
    }
};
```

One solution that comes to my mind is to create a vector and copy the values:

```
class Socket {
    template <...>
    bool send(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
         std::vector<...> buff(begin, end);
         socket_send(buffer.data(), buffer.size()*sizeof(decltype(buffer)::value_type);
    }
};
```

The problem, that I have with this solution, is the unneccessary copy of the data even if it is already contigious memory.

Is there a generic and efficient solution around this problem?

Comment: The nice thing about C++ is that you can overload functions. You could easily have one `send` function taking iterators and copying the data, then you could have a more "raw" `send` function which takes a pointer and a size (much like the underlying `socket_send` function it calls). Then you could use either depending on the needs you have for any specific situation.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude is it possible to overload on std::vector<>::iterator. For this iterator i know, that the memory is contigious.

Comment: @OutOfBound Can you use just socket_send( &*begin, std;:distance( begin, end) );?

Comment: Can't you overload based on iterator tags (https://fr.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags)? If it's a `std::random_access_iterator_tag`, then it's contiguous and you should be able to dereference `begin` and `end` and get the size from their difference.

Comment: @sturcotte06 std::deque is not contigious, but its iterators are random access.

Comment: @sturcotte06 Contiguity and random access are two different concepts

Comment: We will have `contiguous_iterator_tag` soon though!

Comment: @OutOfBound Oh thanks, I thought one meant the other.

Comment: You might want to look into ASIO for a [scatter-gather async_send](http://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_3_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html#boost_asio.reference.buffer.buffers_and_scatter_gather_i_o). It takes a collection of discontinuous buffers for a truly zero-copy send.

Comment: "I would like to provide an iterator based interface" Why? It will no doubt just make everything slower, for nothing gained. Perhaps you can find a way to `std::copy` into the C function parameter directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general solution to this, because iterators do not know whether the range they represent is *contiguous*. Only pointers (okay these are a kind of iterator too) know that. Furthermore, your C API necessarily assumes this.

So, there is already a very small domain of uses for your proposed Iterator wrapper. In every case that it will be useful, your source data (e.g. a vector) will already have a way to trivially obtain a pointer and a size. In every other case, you will have to copy the data into a new vector, which you've correctly said is not optimal.

Therefore, you are better off simply *not doing this*. The existing interface is already exactly as it should be.

If you already have vector iterators, you can map to the C interface like `socket_send((void*)&*begin, std::distance(begin, end))`. You *could* make an forwarding overload for these (*specifically for vector iterators*), but is there really much point? `socket_send(vec.data(), vec.size())` is nice.

And if you do *really* need to accept arbitrary ranges then, fine, do your copy. But note that the standard typically doesn't provide "automatic" or "implicit" or "easy-to-call" features for techniques that cost a lot (e.g. there is no random access for lists, because that would be expensive), and I suggest you take the same approach.

---

[From C++20 we will have `contiguous_iterator_tag`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags), which you could use to disable your generic interface for incompatible iterator ranges. Again, though, I'd question the utility of this since in such cases you already have the information you need in the C API form.

Comment: So suggestion is to have one pointer based call for already contigious memory and one iterator based for the non contigious memory.

Comment: No my suggestion is to use the existing interface and move on to more important tasks :)

Comment: Are you saying that you do need to accept _arbitrary_ iterator ranges? It's not quite clear what your goal is.

Comment: that would be the ideal case, because it would work with std::string and std::vector and a couple more.